# AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I have a Rails 4 app with Paperclip running on Heroku. I recently started encountering a problem that is preventing me from updating any models with attached images. For example, any time I make a change through my site's CMS system to my `Company` model, the changes are not saved. I've tried changing only the image, the image and various other attributes, and only non-image attributes. It's as if the `@company.save` is never called in my controller's update action.

I found [this issue report](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1416) and tried the various solutions suggested, but nothing worked.

Here is my `Company` model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

In my logs, I get the following error:

```
[AWS S3 404 0.022711 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"myApp",:key=>"companies/profile_photos/000/000/118/original/2015-09-05_19.05.34.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key
```

I verified that my S3 credentials are set using `heroku config` and that they are valid.

I'm not certain, but I suspect that this may have something to do with my recent addition of the following buildpacks:

```
=== myApp Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack.git
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

I've not been able to reproduce the problem on localhost.

**Update**

I've since opened up an [issue report](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2015) on this problem.

Here is my `config.paperclip_defaults` block in `production.rd`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_protocol => :https,
    :s3_host_name => 's3.amazonaws.com',
    :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
}
```

Here is my `aws.yml`:

```
development:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>

production:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Documentation from the GitHub paperclip wiki

Assuming you are using dotenv-rails...

In development.rb and production.rb files:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_host_name: ENV['S3_HOST_NAME'],
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

Make sure to set these variables in your Heroku environment:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_HOST_NAME=your-s3-hostname-here S3_BUCKET_NAME=your-production-bucket-name-here
```

[Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3)

## Documentation from rubydoc.info

This states you should have a yaml file with these details specified or write a method on your model.

[rubydoc.info Paperclip::Storage::S3](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)

Comment: I just amended my question above with my config block. Pretty similar. I've had the same block since the beginning. Also the same setup for development, though the error doesn't occur in development.

Comment: Similar, but not the same.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion but it made no difference. See edits to my post for the code. I was trying earlier to `pry-remote` into the controller but could't get `pry-remote` to work.

Comment: New development. I thought to throw in a `puts @company.valid?` and `@company.errors` into the controller, which revealed that it's failing validation, although why I'm not yet sure.

Comment: What does `@company.errors.full_messages` return? It could be failing validations since it is unable to save the associated image attachment.

Comment: Based on what you have posted so far, I am inclined think the issue is with the bucket name. Move the setting of the bucket definition one level up in your `production.rb` file (eg- not nested under `:s3_credentials`).

Comment: I solved it. Turns out it had absolutely nothing to do with Paperclip or S3. I threw in a `puts @company.errors.messages` and it turns out one of my nested models was failing a validation silently. I fixed the validation problem and now it works again. I seriously thought I was going crazy. I'm giving you the bounty for giving me that idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`No Such Key` is S3's way of saying "404 Not Found."

I don't believe it has any alternate meanings.

The request was authorized and syntactically valid, but there's no file in the bucket at the specified path.

You may want to inspect the contents of your bucket from the AWS console.

Comment: So when I check the bucket, the folder `companies/profile_photos/00/00/118` doesn't exist. The folders go up to `113` only. What I want to know is why the attachment isn't being saved. I have other models with paperclip attachments and identical validations, which work just fine. There are no errors raised or logged, so I don't know where to begin looking.